# How can I communicate between a server and client in a ASP.NET webapp?

Tags: asp.net, client-server, blazor

I want to make a pictionary like webapp.

I chose to develop using the .net platform, and decided to make a blazor client with a asp.net server, but I don't know how to communicate between them.

When a player is drawing something, as he/she draws, whatever he/she is drawing should appear on the other player's client, but I don't know how should to send this data to the server and back to the other clients.

I took a look at gRPC but don't know if this is the right tool for this kind of communication assuming a tickrate of 20 to 50 times a second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may create a Blazor WebAssembly App, which is running on the browser, and whose default means of transport is HTTP. However, you can use SignalR Client for your requirements. This is the way to go. Look up in the docs for the sample of creating a chat app in Blazor WebAssembly employing SignalR Client. There are also code samples created by the community demonstrating how to create advanced chat applications and games, and every thing involving that.

Good luck...