# Secure Blazor WebAssembly set-up for a game server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, webassembly, blazor-client-side

I've been looking to implement a simple web-browser game. Blazor WebAssembly seems really neat, but exposing all my code (.dlls) is something I'd like to avoid. For this reason, I've been planning to have 2 separate projects - **Blazor WebAssembly** project with client-side logic and an **Asp.NET Rest server** to handle Rest requests from the client, database communication, game/account logic and game updates.

**Currently my prototype looks as follows:**

1. WebAssembly project

   1. A page sending a http request + showing results
2. Rest server

   1. Controller class handling the GET request

The prototype works, *but* the nature of the application requires me to be running updates of data and evaluation of game state server-side every now and then (think game loop, but in my case I only need to run it a few times a day).

I have no idea how to handle that with the current approach - **how do I ensure, that the Rest Server doesn't start handling a breaking request in the middle of updating the game state/updating database?** Do I implement some thread-safe solution within the Controller classes? Is there something available out of the box?

If the whole 'game state update' takes little time (few seconds tops) **do I have to worry about blocking clients waiting for their HTTP requests to get served?**

And lastly: **How do I handle updating the client-side page with data once the game update is performed?** My current idea is to have clients periodically ask the server if there are any updates.

Comment: You are aware of what databases do? What ACID conditions mean? Most of your questions sound like "I have no idea that databases guarantee atomicity".

Comment: You're right that they do, but I can be performing multiple DB updates that make up a game state and don't want to respond to a GET request in the middle of that, providing incomplete/wrong state to the client.

Comment: Yeah, you can - if you reda uncommited data from the database.

Comment: @TomTom You're right, this does make my questions seem stupid. I'll blame this one on my lack of experience and knowledge in this area. Thank you for pointing that out :)

Comment: Basically you need a defined "truth" that you can rely on. If you do not have a performance issue, databases are a defined truth - that is what they ARE. The problem is not sending correct data - that is trivial as per database. The problem comes when you must add caching for performance reasons and can NOT rely on he database providing the truth. Then things get interesting.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61642412/how-can-i-communicate-between-a-server-and-client-in-a-asp-net-webapp/61642712#61642712